# Getting 404 error when adding routes in Akka Http

Tags: scala, akka-http

I am writing a simple route in Akka-Http to understand the routing mechanism. My routes file is

```
  val newsApiRoutes = get {
    pathSingleSlash {
      complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`, "<html><body>Simple Get Request</body></html>"))
    } ~
      path("ping") {
        complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`, "<html><body>Playing Ping Pong</body></html>"))
      }
  }
```

When I hit the endpoint `http://localhost:8080/ping` I get the output `Playing Ping Pong` which is on expected lines. But now as I add one more route

```
 val newsApiRoutes = get {
    pathSingleSlash {
      complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`, "<html><body>Simple Get Request</body></html>"))
    } ~
      path("ping") {
        pathSingleSlash{
          path("pong"){
            complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`, "<html><body>Playing Ping Pong</body></html>"))
          }
        }
      }
  }
```

and I hit the endpoint with `http://localhost:8080/ping/pong` I get 404 Error citing `The requested resource could not be found.` Can anyone let me know where exactly I am going wrong. Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: From [docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/path-directives/path.html): _The `path` directive attempts to match the complete remaining path, not just a prefix. If you only want to match a path prefix and then delegate further filtering to a lower level in your routing structure use the `pathPrefix` directive instead._ So, just go for `pathPrefix("ping")`.

Comment: @YevheniiPopadiuk replacing path with pathPrefix does not work.

Comment: My bad. You also don't need the `pathSingleSlash` here, as `path` consumes leading slash. Hope it works fine now.

Comment: That works. Thanks